# Active Directory - Trust Relationship Error

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

Early in the morning, I have a computer which consistently can't be logged in to. When I try to login, I get the following error message:

```
The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
```

However, if I try again later in the morning, it logs in without error. I do not have to manually re-establish the domain trust.

In the Windows Event Viewer, it says:

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. 
Windows could not authenticate to the Active Directory service on a domain controller. 
(LDAP Bind function call failed). Look in the details tab for error code and description.
```

The errorCode on the details tab is 82. I read [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727283%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on the above error message and they do not document errorCode 82 (only errorCodes 5, 49, and 258).

Does anyone have any ideas why this occurs and how to fix it?